# Show javascript loading icon while php exec() is executing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a PHP page that executes a python script on load and once the script is executed, displays the rest of the page, which are the set of few divs..

```
<?php

$str = exec('python -u read.py ' . $params, $output);
$str;

echo "welcome";
echo "<div id='div_1'>";
  echo "<div id = 'div_2'>";
  echo "you have finally landed, dude!";
  echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

?>
```

The issue is that the script takes like 8 to 9 (or sometimes 12) seconds to execute completely (via exec() function)..and for this reason, I need to display a javascript loading icon as long as the script executes, and then hide it once the script has executed completely..what are the easiest (and not easiest) ways of approaching this? thanks.

Comment: you will have to use `.ajax()` for it. [read documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). load the page without the relevant content then issue an async call to the PHP script.

Comment: Not the most graceful, but maybe the easiest. Show the spinner gif then exec the python script and cache it or store the results in a database. Then redirect using meta tag. The page will load fast if cached so you will not need the spinner if pulling from cache. Users will also appreciate not having to wait for the python script each time the page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this image with your html earlier, when you first load the page.

```
<img id="img" src="loader.gif">
```

Then execute the php script using this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = "http://link_to_your_php_script";
    $.post(url, { /* You can have variable to post here */ }, function(data){
        if(data=="error"){
        alert("Error,page couldn't be loaded.");
        }
        else{
                  $("#id").html(data);
                }

        });
     $("#img").hide(); //Hide the loading image.

});
```

Change `#id` to `#'id of element where you want to place the <div>....</div>'`.

You don't need to change the php script. You can place in your php script.

```
echo  "error";
exit;
```

if there is an error.

A better thing would be to change your php in the bottom part to,

```
echo "welcome
     <div id='div_1'>
           <div id = 'div_2'>
           you have finally landed, dude!
     </div>
    </div>";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout(function(){    
    document.getElementById("div_1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
}, 1200);
```

Then add following line

```
   echo "<div id='loading'>Loding......</div>";
```

I hope this will  help you, All the best!

Answer (score 0):

add this line `<img id="img" src="loader.gif" style="display:none;">` before `echo "<div id='div_1'>";`

```
<!----------code to show loading image after submitting form, before the content is fully loaded--------------->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#form1").submit(function() { //you can assign id to your form and used that id instead of form
$("#img").show();
$("#img").addClass("iimg");
$("div#div_1").hide();
return true;
});

});
</script>
<style>
    .iimg{
        margin-top:150px;
        height:15px;
        width:140px;
    }
</style>
<!-------------------------------------->
```

Comment: No. Before the `exec(...)`.